# To fetch the field name along with their values and edit it in php

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to fetch the field name along with their values from a table dynamically(because i have to select the the table from a drop-down so we can't specify the field-name as field-name may vary from one table to another) and the value should editable so that it can be updated...? if yes how?
Here is my code. I have printed the value but not able to **edit,update and format** it..

```
$result = mysqli_query("select * from 2mcom where father_name='Siyaram'");
while (false != ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)))
  foreach ($data as $key => $value)
  echo "$key: $value <br />";
```

this is my table:

```
student_name  father_name  sub1  sub2

  kunwar        Siyaram    20     40
```

Output value of table along with their field name as:

```
Student_name : kunwar
father_name : Siyaram
sub1  : 20
sub2  : 40
```

Comment: you want to fetch data from different tables?

Comment: Do you want to dispaly the data in textfield?

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

Comment: what you mean by not edit update you already have fields name?

Comment: @sgt: yes from different table and display it in text field so that i can edit and update it..it is for result correction.

Comment: so you also need the column names to i think.

Comment: @Sgt: yes i need the column name and its value. and i have done up-to this but the value should be editable means it need to come in text-box

Comment: simply display them in input fields then.

Comment: @Sgt : I have tried its not coming..Its printing simply $value not the actual value

Comment: plz add the code where you added the values.

Comment: <?php
include('include/config.php');

$result = mysql_query("select * from 2mcom where father_name='Siyaram'");
while (false != ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))){
  foreach ($data as $key => $value){
   echo "$key: ";
  
    ?>
<input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo '$value'; ?> " />
<?php echo "<br>"; }} ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<table>" ;
    $result = mysqli_query("select * from 2mcom where roll_no='138218600004'");
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            $name = 'field';
            $id = $row['roll_no']; //rename this with your row id, this will give you identifiable input names
            echo '<tr><td>';
            echo $key . ': ';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<form method="POST">';
            echo '<td>';

            echo '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'. $row['roll_no'] .'"/>';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="column[]" value="'. $key .'"/>';
            echo '<input type="text" name="field[]" value="'. $value .'"/>';

            echo '</td></tr>';
        }
        $i++;
    } 
      echo "<tr><td>";
       echo'<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>';
      echo "</tr></td>";
        echo'</form></table>';
```

Comment: In your initial layout you were using mysqli functions which still work. In this answer you've switched to mysql functions which are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Using your values for DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME

Note, you can use the Object oriented style for mysqli.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$result = $mysqli->query("select * from 2mcom where father_name='Siyaram'");
```

OR the Procedural style as with your code. But you must include the `$link` as follows:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
mysqli_query($link, "select * from 2mcom where father_name='Siyaram'")
```

The rest of the code:
** UPDATED to show editing **

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

/* Get field information for all columns */
while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
    $afinfo[] = $finfo;
}

?>
    <form action="YourForm.php" method="post" >
<?php
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    foreach ($afinfo as $col){
?>
        <?php echo $col->name ?>: <input type="text" name="<?php echo $col->name ?>" value="<?php echo $row[$col->name] ?>"><br>
<?php      
    }    
?>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" >
    </form>
```

Comment: Its the same thing i have done up-to..I want to edit the value

Comment: I initially posted this comment to the wrong answer. I've updated my code to show how to edit. You of course need to have the code to process the POST of the edited data.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the column names for each table when you're pulling the tabl enames for the dropdown with a query like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
  [AND column_name LIKE 'wild']
```

Comment: I have done up to fetching the field-name and its value. The problem is its not editable.